# Using Laravel 5, JQuery? Pusher? create a live data page

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, live

I am currently learning Laravel making a cart system, I am trying to make a "live" dashboard page that displays new orders as they are created in the database without someone having to refresh the page. I have searched for answers but none seem to work, I'm guessing this is a simple get request?

Route:

```
Route::get('/staff', [
'uses' => 'StaffController@getIndex',
'as' => 'staff',
'middleware' => 'roles',
'roles' => ['Manager', 'Pizzaiolo']
]);
```

Controller function:

```
   public function getIndex()   {

    $orders_open = Order::where('order_complete', 0)->get();
    $orders_open->transform(function($order, $key) {
        $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
        return $order;
    });

    $orders_closed = Order::where('order_complete', 1)
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->get();
    $orders_closed->transform(function($order, $key) {
        $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
        return $order;
    });
    return view('staff.dashboard', ['orders_open' => $orders_open, 'orders_closed' => $orders_closed]);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: This has really more to do with jquery than Laravel. You might want to update your question (title) to be less Laravel specific so you can get more answers.

Comment: The typical implementation would basically involve the dashboard page using some jquery to do an ajax request to your controller (periodically using setInterval()), which then returns a json object of the data. jQuery would then be used to modify the objects on the page to change the page when the data changes.

Comment: Is that the return json?